# Rails change boolean value with checkbox and jquery ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery, routes, boolean

I am new to rails and trying to change the value of a boolean via a checkbox and using jquery ajax:

```
<%- @tasks.each do |task| %>
  <div class="task-wrapper">
    <%= check_box_tag 'completed', task.id , task.completed, :class => "task-check" %>
    <%= content_tag :span, task.task %>
    <%= content_tag :span, task.deadline %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

and the javascript:

```
$(".task-check").bind('change', function(){
  if (this.checked){
    var bool = this.checked ? 1 : 0;
    $.ajax({
      url: '/todos/toggle',
      type: 'POST',
      data: '{"task_id":"'+ this.value +'", "bool":"'+ bool +'"}'
    });
  }
  else {
    alert("no");
  }
});
```

then the controller:

```
def toggle(task_id, bool)
  @task = Todo.find_by_id(task_id)

  if @task != nil?
    @task.update_attributes(:completed => bool)
  else
    set_flash "Error, please try again"
  end
end
```

finally the routes:

```
resources :todos do
  member do
    post 'toggle'
  end
end
```

> also tried collection but gives the same error.

when ever i try it i get a `404 error` on the action.

what is the problem?

thanks

Comment: Is your task loop inside a form?

Comment: @Catfish - no its outside the form

Comment: Why don't you put it inside a form? It'd be much simpler. Then instead of `check_box_tag` you can use `f.check_box`.

Comment: @Catfish - But how would i change the `bool` without a postback?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try the following (leaving everything else as is):

the javascript:

```
$(".task-check").bind('change', function(){
  if (this.checked){
    $.ajax({
      url: '/todos/'+this.value+'/toggle',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {"completed": this.checked}
    });
  }
  else {
     alert("no");
  }
});
```

the controller:

```
def toggle
  @task = Todo.find(params[:id])

  if @task.update_attributes(:completed => params[:completed])
    # ... update successful
  else
    # ... update failed
  end
end
```

Take a look at `bundle exec rake routes` to show you the paths that rails generates. In the case of your `post 'toggle'` which is a member you get a path like `/todos/:id/toggle`, hence the updated url in the ajax.

In the controller the `:id` from the path ends up in `params[:id]`. The data from the ajax request also ends up in the `params` hash, hence `params[:completed]`.

Comment: This works great, could you please explain why it does? Thanks

Comment: Note that Rails 4 adds a simpler way, as noted below

Answer (score 44):

As of Rails 4, there's a way to do this without needing any additional JS or CSS:

```
<%= check_box_tag 'completed', task.id, task.completed,
      data: {
        remote: true,
        url: url_for(action: :toggle, id: task.id),
        method: "POST"
      } %>
```

It turns out that adding `remote: true` to an input causes jquery-ujs to make it ajax-y in all the nice ways. Thoughtbot's ["A Tour of Rails jQuery UJS"](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/a-tour-of-rails-jquery-ujs#ajax-forms) briefly touches this (and many other good things available); the ["Unobtrusive scripting support for jQuery" page](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/Unobtrusive-scripting-support-for-jQuery) in the jQuery UJS wiki does a thorough job on this as well.

Comment: Also available for earlier versions of rails, not exactly sure which ones, but last version of 3 works.

Comment: Still working for rails 5.1.6 and 5.2. This is the best awnser here.