# Rails, Ajax, and boolean; can't uncheck box

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I know there are a bunch of related questions out there, but I can't get mine to work. Here is what I have...

```
#app/views/tasks/index.html.erb
<%- @tasks.each do |task| %>
  <div class="task-wrapper">
    <%= check_box_tag 'checked_in', task.id , task.checked_in, :class => "task-check" %>
    <%= content_tag :span, task.name %>
  </div>
<% end %>
<%= link_to 'New Task', new_task_path %>

  <script>
$(".task-check").bind('change', function(){
  if (this.checked){
    $.ajax({
      url: '/tasks/'+this.value+'/toggle',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {"checked_in": this.checked}
    });
  }
  else {
     alert("no");
  }
});
  </script>

#app/controllers/tasks_controller.rb
...
def toggle
  @task = Task.find(params[:id])

  if @task.update_attributes(:checked_in => params[:checked_in])
    # do I need something here?
  else
    # do I need something here?
  end
end
...
```

My task model has a 'checked_in' attribute that is boolean.

I got this code from this question...

[Rails change boolean value with checkbox and jquery ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15572371/rails-change-boolean-value-with-checkbox-and-jquery-ajax)

...and don't quite understand everything that is going on. When I create a new task I can successfully check the box to set my boolean value to true. However, when I uncheck the box I get the js pop-up that says "No", but nothing get set in the DB, and nothing is sent back to server.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

The problem comes from your js code

```
$(".task-check").bind('change', function(){
  if (this.checked){
    $.ajax({
      url: '/tasks/'+this.value+'/toggle',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {"checked_in": this.checked}
    });
  } 
  else {
    alert("no");
  }  
});
```

When you check/uncheck the box, the `change`event is triggered, then the function is testing `this.checked`. It returns false `false` when the box is unchecked, so you don't go inside the  condition but directly in the `else`, which calls `alert`.

So you probably want to remove the condition.

Answer (score 2):

Thats how browsers work. They dont send the value of unchecked checkboxes.

Check/Uncheck need to be determined based on the presence of the parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Antoine. That worked...doing the best I can to learn JS. For posterity here is what worked...

## app/views/tasks/index.html.erb

```
<%- @tasks.each do |task| %>
  <div class="task-wrapper">
    <%= check_box_tag 'checked_in', task.id , task.checked_in, :class => "task-check" %>
    <%= content_tag :span, task.name %>
  </div>
<% end %>
<%= link_to 'New Task', new_task_path %>

  <script>
$(".task-check").bind('change', function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: '/tasks/'+this.value+'/toggle',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {"checked_in": this.checked}
    });
});
  </script>
```

...additionally I was getting a template error being thrown in the console, so here is updated controller code.

```
  def toggle
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])
    @task.update_attributes(:checked_in => params[:checked_in])
    render :nothing => true
  end
```

Comment: You're welcome. Also, for your next questions, if you want to provide the solution that worked for you (which is nice), you should edit the question, instead of making another post.
Posts are reserved for answers, and their orders might change over time.