# How to make an Ajax checkbox callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

Building off "[Rails change boolean value with checkbox and jquery ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15572371/rails-change-boolean-value-with-checkbox-and-jquery-ajax/34645524#34645524)", I tried to build a checkbox Ajax POST call.

The call seems to work, but there's no way to attach a callback that I can see.

In the "[Working with JavaScript in Rails](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html)", you seem to be able to do it via this code:

```
$(document).ready ->
    $("#new_article").on("ajax:success", (e, data, status, xhr) ->
        $("#new_article").append xhr.responseText
    ).on "ajax:error", (e, xhr, status, error) ->
        $("#new_article").append "<p>ERROR</p>"
```

But this doesn't seem to work.

When I attach it to the checkbox class (so instead of `new_article`) nothing gets fired after the successful hit. Any thoughts? Am I supposed to attach it to something else? I looked in the code and no form gets generated around my checkbox.

Here are more [links](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/ajax) that seem to support that the previous JavaScript code was how it's supposed to work, but isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using `remote: true`, you'll be able to use the [following](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/check_box_tag#1383-Using-an-unobtrusive-Ajax-UJS-onchange-call-to-the-controller-action):

```
#view
<%= check_box_tag :param_name, "value", false, id: "check_box", data: { remote: true, url: your_path} %>
```

--

`remote: true` invokes the [`rails_ujs`](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs), which has a series of [event hooks](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/ajax) (you're using above). You need to bind your JS to these event hooks in order to retrieve the response you want:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.coffee
$(document).on("ajax:success", "#check_box", (data, status, xhr) -> 
    $("#new_article").append xhr.responseText
).on "ajax:error", "#check_box", (e, xhr, status, error) ->
    $("#new_article").append "Error"
```

Several things to understand:

1. If you have [`turbolinks`](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks) enabled, always [delegate](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) from the `document` object (JQuery can only bind to elements loaded with the `DOM`)
2. If you're trying to "catch" an Ajax response (in this case from your `remote: true`), it needs to be bound to the element *sending* the request. Normally, this would be a form but in your case, it's the checkbox

---

This, of course, relies on the idea you're sending a request via the `rails_ujs` `remote: true` helper. Contrary, if you wanted to send a request with "naked" JQuery, you'd want to use:

```
#view
<%= form_tag ... do %> 
  <%= check_box_tag :x, "y", id: "check_box" %>
<% end %>

#app/assets/javascripts/application.coffee
$(document).on "change", "#check_box", (e) ->
   $.ajax
      url: "your/path/as/a/string",
      data: $(this).val(),
      success: (data) ->
        // do something,
      error: (data) ->
        // do something
```

Comment: Great answer as usual @RichPeck

Comment: as expected, it didn't work when i tried it, but when you answered it, it works! i still don't know what i did wrong, but it's going right now. also note that you need to send a response in JSON format.