# Rails change object, using checkbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The object `Task` contains a `boolean` field `complete`. How to change the status of the object by pressing the checkbox?

**Task model:**

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project

  scope :complete, -> { where(done: true) }
  scope :incomplete, -> { where(done: nil) }

  def mark_complete!
    self.update_attribute(:done, true)
  end

end
```

**Task Controller:**

```
def done
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])
    @task.mark_complete!
  end
```

**routes.rb:**

```
get '/done/:id', to: 'tasks#done', as: 'done'
```

**done.js.erb:** `$('#row_<%= task.id %>').css("background-color", "yellow");`

**View task#_task.html.erb:**

```
<tr id="row_<%= task.id %>" data-item-id=<%= "#{task.id}" %> class="item">
  <td><%= task.name %></td>
  <td><%= task.done %></td>
  <td><%= link_to "Mark Complete", done_path(task), remote: true %></td>
  <td><%= link_to '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>'.html_safe, task_path(task), remote: true,
                  class: 'btn btn-xs',
                  method: :delete,
                  data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'} %></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/15572371/5076451

Comment: By pressing what checkbox? Can you show us the code you have for what you've tried so far?

Comment: @jeffdill2 Yes, I've updated the question

Comment: @AlexandrDmitrenko much better. :-)

Comment: @AlexandrDmitrenko I still don't see a checkbox. I assume you mean you want to change the status of the `Task` object by pressing the "Mark Complete" button?

Comment: @jeffdill2 To be honest , I just do not know how to do it with the help of checkbox. I need to at the touch of a checkbox, Ajax changes the status of an object

Comment: @AlexandrDmitrenko no worries. One more question - do you specifically need it to be AJAX (I'm assuming yes, since it looks like you're building something like a To-Do app) or can it be a form submission (i.e. the page will refresh)?

Comment: @jeffdill2 Yes you are right! I make To-Do app)) I need - what would you press the `checkbox` , using the `Ajax` changed object status. Without refreshing the page. If the `checkbox` is pressed - the status is `true` , else -`false`

Comment: what is problem with your answer/Question @AlexandrDmitrenko? I think you have complete working code. Any specific problem?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

#### routes.rb

```
resources :tasks do
  collection do
    put :mark_complete
  end
end
```

#### tasks_controller.rb

```
def mark_complete
  task = Task.find(params[:task_id])
  
  if task.mark_complete!
    render json: task.done?, status: :ok
  else
    render json: task.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end
```

#### task.html.erb

```
...

<td><%= link_to "Mark Complete", "javascript:void(0)", class: "mark-complete", data_task_id: task.id %></td>

...

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '.mark-complete', function() {
      var taskId = $(this).data('taskId');

      $.ajax({
        url: "#{mark_complete_tasks_path}",
        type: 'PUT',
        data: { task_id: taskId },
        success: function(response, status, xhr) {
          // Whatever you want to do here with the item that was marked complete.
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
          console.log(xhr, status, error);
        },
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Routing Error: `No route matches [PUT] "/tasks"`

Comment: What is the output of `rake routes | grep task` for you?

Comment: [routes](http://joxi.ru/D2PDZbludljJ02). And please tell me, what was specified in my routes.rb: 

scope :complete, -> { where(done: true) }
scope :incomplete, -> { where(done: nil) }

def mark_complete!
self.update_attribute(:done, true)
end
> I remove it?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.

Comment: Your routes look good. Where is the `No route matches...` error occuring?

Comment: I added your code - overloaded the project. But by pressing the link `Mark Complete` nothing happens. In the google developer console -> network, I see this error .

Comment: `scope :complete, -> { where(done: true) }
  scope :incomplete, -> { where(done: nil) }

  def mark_complete!
    self.update_attribute(:done, true)
  end` I can delete?

Comment: @AlexandrDmitrenko this conversation would be better suited for a private chat. I just had somebody else upvote your question to get you to the required 20 reputation points to do a private chat, so as soon as that takes affect, I'll invite you to a chat and we can continue this conversation. :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105272/discussion-between-jeffdill2-and-alexandr-dmitrenko).

Answer (score 0):

**routes.rb:**

```
resources :tasks do
    member do
      post 'done'
    end
  end
```

**Controller:**

```
def done
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])
    @task.update_attributes(:done => params[:done])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js {}
    end

  end
```

**View:**

```
....
 <td><%= task.done %></td>
 <td><%= check_box_tag 'done', task.id , task.done, :class => "task-check", remote: true %></td>
....

<script>
  $(".task-check").bind('change', function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: '/tasks/'+this.value+'/done',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {"done": this.checked},
    });
  });

</script>
```

**tasks#done.js.erb:** `window.location.reload();`